# Rails 3.1 asset pipeline css styles in 404 static page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I am building a static public/404.html page. Before Rails 3.1 I can reference it with the public/style.css. But now with asset pipeline I am not sure what to link to. I heard that the styles will be compiled into `asset/application.css`. But on production it will come with a timestamp.

What is the best approach to style the static 404.html with the normal styles I work with?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's true that the assets in 3.1 come with a digest in production, but you can still use the regular file, meaning that you can link to `/assets/application.css` and you won't have any problems (try it! :)).

Comment: Thanks! I guess this means I can't check those in development environment? As in dev css files are not merged.

Comment: You should be able to do it too. If you call `/assets/application.css` you'll see all the concatenated code. If you call it with the `?body=1` option you'll only see what's in that specific file.

Comment: ...and if you're using far-future expiration headers then doesn't this solution leave you pretty screwed?  What if you update your application.css and the users already have that file cached.  They'll not get your updated styles.

Comment: Since Rails 4.0, there are no assets generated without digest.

Comment: Since Rails 4 will add a digest hash to assets, you can add a task to your deployment process that looks like this:
    `cp #{release_path}/public/assets/500-*.html #{release_path}/public/500.html`

Answer (score 16):

You can precompile static error pages with asset pipeline too!

Inside `application.rb`:

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/html"
config.assets.precompile += %w(404.html 500.html)
```

Create in `assets/html/` files `404.html.erb` and `500.html.erb` and use many helpers there, like `stylesheet_link_tag, javascript_include_tag, image_tag`.

Then setup your server to use precompiled `public/assets/404.html` and `public/assets/500.html`

All credits for this clever solution goes to http://neovintage.blogspot.cz/2012/02/precompile-static-html-pages-with-rails.html

Comment: In Rails 4, this is also necessary: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284278/how-to-include-actionview-helpers-in-the-assets-pipeline

Comment: Also they MUST be erb files, not HAML http://icelab.com.au/articles/precompiled-rails-static-404-and-500-pages/

Comment: There is another nice solution for HAML error pages: http://devoh.com/blog/2012/09/asset-pipeline-error-pages