# How to include ActionView helpers in the assets pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, actionviewhelper

How to include Rails view helpers to be accesible by assets pipeline execution context?

An example use case would be to generate the markup for a form, using `form_tag` helper method, and make it available to a Javascript template (like handlebars, jst, etc.).

I use handlebar_assets gem, but this should apply to any `erb` or `haml` template too.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Create a inititializer and include the helpers in the context of the assets like this:

```
Rails.application.assets.context_class.class_eval do
  include ActionView::Helpers
  include MyAppHelper
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
end
```

Taken from this [sprockets issue](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/issues/218)

Comment: This also worked for me when I wanted to render a custom ERB to string with `template = ERB.new(html)
    template.result(binding)`.  Without this I wasn't able to use concat and other simple helpers.

Comment: @brutuscat, can you clarify where you would put this code? Thanks

Comment: @jackerman09 no problem: "Create a inititializer", see more here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#using-initializer-files

Comment: reference: https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/307#issuecomment-170707886

Answer (score 15):

The above answer is now out of date. As of sprockets-rails 3, the appropriate interface is a configure block, like so:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.configure do |env|
  env.context_class.class_eval do
    # include SomeHelper
  end
end
```

This configure block should still be placed in an initializer.

reference: https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails/issues/307#issuecomment-170707886