# mix handlebars with erb

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, erb, sprockets

In Rails 3.2 I was able to rename a extension to `.handlebars.erb` in order to be able to use erb tags (mainly `<%= image_tag 'image.jpg' %>`) in my handlebars templates.

I'm unable to get this going in Rails 4. Im using

```
gem 'ember-rails'
gem 'handlebars-source'
```

The error I'm getting:

```
undefined method `image_tag'
```

The view in question is the one below, same for any other view:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span12">
    <div class="row-fluid distance_0">
      <div class="row-fluid divider slide_divider base_color_background">
        <div class="container">
          <span class="bottom_arrow"></span>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Title and Description -->
      <div class="row-fluid slide_content fullwidth">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row-fluid text_bar_pattern themeple_sc">
            <div class="content_bar">
              <h3>
              </h3>
              <p>
              </p>
            </div>
            {{#linkTo "user.new" class="button_bar"}}{{/linkTo}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="bottom_shadow_full"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row-fluid distance_2"></div>
      <div class="row-fluid distance_2"></div>
      <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="container">
          <img src="images/old_letters_blur.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>

      <%= image_tag 'old_letters_blur.jog' %>

      <!-- TextBar -->
      <!-- TextBar End -->

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: @claptimes you're right, added the error

Comment: Can you add the source for the view in question?

Comment: @claptimes I added the view, it's the same for all view really, must be missing something obvious in hte asset pipeline.

Comment: Did you upgrade from Rails 3 to Rails 4?

Comment: @claptimes no, it's a fresh rails 4 / ruby 2 / ember 1.0 project.

Comment: Answer here works for me:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284278/how-to-include-actionview-helpers-in-the-assets-pipeline#answer-14284279