# Include ActionController::Base outside of views directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I can have a view file that contains only this:

*root/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb*

```
<%= link_to root_url %>
```

And of course it works. This is because

```
ActionController
```

is included in the view file somehow.

**How does this work? Inside each view we don't write 'include ActionController' so how is it magically included?**

Let's say I'm using an angular template:

*root/app/assets/templates/angularview.html.erb*

```
<%= link_to root_url %>
```

Everything works perfectly apart from the fact that the link_to isn't included in this view:

```
undefined method `link_to' for #<#<Class:0x000000020417b0>:0x0000000468f2c8>
```

1. **How should I include ActionController into a file stored at *root/app/assets/templates/angularview.html.erb*?**
2. **What should I edit in my project to automatically make all files inside *root/app/assets/templates* include ActionController? Is this possible? I want them to behave like 'normal' views, and magically include everything a normal view includes.**

Comment: It is the opposite way. When a new request comes to app, new instance of `ActionController::Base` is created (or any descendant) and then handles it and respond with content of your view.

Comment: @blelump Is it possible to do this for a file stored outside of the views directory?

Comment: You need controller context or at least include appropriate helper. I think there's some solution for `Angular`, but I'm not using it and I think I can't help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working as you have your angularview template in assets directory(as you have mentioned in your question: ***root/app/assets/templates/angularview.html.erb***). You need to create it inside your application's ***app/views/layouts/*** directory.

See these answers for more information:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6951986/645886
2. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19849989/645886

**UPDATE**: However, if you must do that then you can create an initializer and put this code:

```
Rails.application.assets.context_class.class_eval do
  include ActionView::Helpers
  include MyAppHelper
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
end
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14284279/645886

Comment: I want to keep it outside of the views directory. Is it possible to do this? `root/app/assets/templates/` is the correct location for angular templates so it's not like this is some mad idea :)

Comment: I am sorry if you get that impression. I didn't have any bad intention. You can actually use the idea given in those links I posted, however, I'll update it for more clarity, see the updated answer.