# rails add object in javascript url

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I use this function on a js file and it works

```
 $(function() {


$("#badgebutton").click(function() {
    var assertions = [
        "http://www.exemple.com/patents/5555/badge.json"
    ];
    OpenBadges.issue(assertions, function(errors, successes) {
        console.log("callback called");
        console.log("Errors:", errors);
        console.log("Successes:", successes);
    });
});
});
```

In place of the number :

```
"http://www.exemple.com/patents/5555/badge.json"
```

I would like to use the patent.id. I tried this :

```
"http://www.exemple.com/patents/#{@patent.id}/badge.json"
```

and some other solution without success..

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this:

```
"http://www.exemple.com/patents/<%= @patent.id %>/badge.json"
```

But, it's advisable to use routing helper methods generated by Rails when you define them in your routes.rb file. For example:

```
<%= badge_patents_path(@patent, :format => :json) %>
```

Comment: this works fine if I put the javascript in the view, but not on a separate .js file. It give me an error… strange.

Comment: @MAGE that's because Rails helper methods are not available in assets directory. For that you can either have them in available: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26615645/645886 or create a `data-url` attribute on `#badgebutton ` element and then call it in JavaScript: `$(this).data('url')`, if you ask me then I'd prefer latter.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the patent id (or better the whole url) to the js file using JS context which can be done in a few ways:

1. Using globals:

In your partial (erb):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.patent_url = "http://www.exemple.com/patents/#{@patent.id}/badge.json"
</script>
```

Then use the global patent_url variable in the JS file.

2. Redo your JS file to encapsulate the JS logic but receive proper parameters like this.

It could look something like this:

```
window.badgebutton_handler = function(url) {
  OpenBadges.issue(url, function(errors, successes) {
    console.log("callback called");
    console.log("Errors:", errors);
    console.log("Successes:", successes);
  });
}
```

and bind the handler like this in the erb file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#badgebutton").click(function() {
    badgebutton_handler("http://www.exemple.com/patents/#{@patent.id}/badge.json");
  });
</script>
```

The issue is that you should pass the variable or url where you have it and that's the ERB template files.

Comment: 1. By partial, do you mean my view ? because I don't have partial ? 2. I don't understand how to change my JS file like you propose, sorry

Comment: Yes, I meant your view. ERB files are either partials or normal views. I also updated my answer with the full JS file implementation.